# Проблема с nullpointer exeption c Room database android

Tags: java, android, android-room

Проблема в следующем есть приложение уже залитое в плеймаркете, и вылетают исключения в логах консоли плеймаркета Nullpointer exeption. Когда тестирую на виртуальном устройстве вообще таких исключений нет. Прилагаю код. 
MainActivity.java

```html
myAppDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "notepadsdb")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build();
```

Затем к примеру в функции обращаюсь к базе данных

```html
 private void fill_folder_array() {
        Thread th1;
        th1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                folders = MainActivity.myAppDatabase.folderDao().getAllFolders();
            }
        });
        th1.start();

        try{
        category_names.clear();
        category_ids.clear();
            th1.join();
            category_names.add("None");
            category_ids.add(-1);
            for(int i = 0; i< folders.size(); i++){
                category_names.add(folders.get(i).getName());
                category_ids.add(folders.get(i).getId());
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

folders = MainActivity.myAppDatabase.folderDao().getAllFolders(); вот тут вылетает исключение java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at fadeytoday.notepads.createNote$15.run (createNote.java:635)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764) хотя сколько бы не тестил на виртуальном устройстве таких исключений не ловил, и еще есть пара подобных мест в приложении не понимаю в чем может быть проблема

Comment: Ну Вы когда выполняете `folders = MainActivity.myAppDatabase.folderDao().getAllFolders();` в базе данные имеются? Потому что NPE он для всех един. Берешь данные из пустого, лови исключение.

Comment: Я сначала тоже об этом подумал, но эта функции у меня выполняется при создании UI активити(всегда), даже при первом запуске когда база полностью пустая на виртуальном устройстве у меня таких исключений вообще не вылетает, соответственно уже даже не знаю куда копать. Соответственно с другими данными так же. Поэтому хочу понять в чем все таки причина почему у меня нет этих исключений на виртуальном устройстве. И в логах консоли плеймаркета их там меньше процента.

Comment: Удалите полностью приложение, очистите кэш на эмуляторе + clear project и запустите свое приложение. Должна появится NPE.

Comment: Да я даже полностью устроиство виртуальное форматировал и ставил заново.Просто если бы при первом запуске у всех вылетало из за пустых данных в базе то процент бы был дикий. Да и в дальнейшем при использовании.

Comment: `.allowMainThreadQueries()` нельзя использовать в продакшн: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52999851/why-is-recommended-not-to-use-allowmainthreadqueries-for-android-room

Comment: О этого не знал спасибо. А данное исключение разве может из за этого вылетать?

Comment: Если не успевает засетить данные, а где-то уже надо гетить, то да, еще как)

Comment: Спасибо попробую убрать и накатить обнову, если что напишу о результатах.

Comment: Залил обнову не помогло так же сыпятся NullPointerExeption